# How to get the list of unique values for a specific attribute

Tags: c#, solr, indexing, solrnet

I'm trying to get a list of all the unique values for a specific field in my solr index.  I know that the number of unique values is relatively small (<1000), so I shouldn't have any issues parsing them all out, but my current approach is giving me out of memory exceptions when the index has a large number of documents.

Here is what I'm currently trying:

```
public IList<string> GetAllShopNumbers()
        {
            ISolrQuery q= GetSomeSimpleSolrQuery();
            var r = solr.Query(q, new QueryOptions
            {
                Facet = new FacetParameters
                {
                    Queries = new[] {new SolrFacetFieldQuery("shop_number")}
                }
            });

            IList<string> shopNumbers = new List<string>();
            foreach (var facet in r.FacetFields["shop_number"])
            {
                shopNumbers.Add(facet.Key);
            }
            return shopNumbers;
        }
```

As mentioned, this throws an out of memory exception on a large index.  How can we efficiently grab the list of unique values for a specific field in a Solr index?

Comment: Actually, when you try out the Solr query, does it blow out too ?

[http://192.168.0.202:8080/solr/lg_fr_00/select?q=*:*&wt=xml&facet=true&facet.field=shop_number](http://192.168.0.202:8080/solr/lg_fr_00/select?q=*:*&wt=xml&facet=true&facet.field=shop_number)

Comment: @BobYoplait It doesn't blow out, but it's exceedingly slow (> 20 seconds)

Comment: did you use <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" />

Comment: No I didn't.  Why would that configuration be necessary?

Comment: Do you use a TextField ? What is the type of this column in your schema ? Using a TrieIntField will make the facet computation faster. Don't know if that's the only issue though.

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md#pagination